# Extending vector bundles over a regular divisor in a regular affine scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, vector-bundles, algebraic-k-theory

This is more-or-less question (3) on page 170 of Quillen's "Projective Modules over Polynomial Rings" ([link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01390008)):

> Let $A$ be a regular Noetherian ring and let $f \in A$ be an element of $A$ such that $A/(f)A$ is a regular ring. Let $N$ be a finitely generated projective $A[f^{-1}]$-module. Does there necessarily exist a finitely generated projective $A$-module $M$ such that $M \otimes_{A} A[f^{-1}] \simeq N$ as $A[f^{-1}]$-modules?

Keywords: vector bundle, complement, divisor, smooth

Comment: This is known to be true for such local rings containing a field. The affine algebra case was known by a result of Bhatwadekar and Rao (Transactions of the AMS, 1983). Then by a yoga invented by D. Popescu, Popescu deduces it for rings containing a field.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks. I remembered just now that Gabber proves the case when $A$ is regular local of dimension 3, in his thesis "Some theorems on Azumaya algebras", Chapter 1, Theorem 1.

Comment: See also Rao, "On Projective $R_{f_{1} \dotsb f_{t}}$-Modules", American Journal of Mathematics, 1985.